Tuning an Archer upright grand piano?
I'm about to embark on a bold adventure - tuning an Archer upright grand piano for the very first time, with zero formal training. My only guidance is a YouTube video, and I'm wondering... am I crazy?!
Will I somehow magically manage to tune the piano without causing any damage, or will I end up inflicting harm on this beautiful instrument? I'm a firm believer that with the right mindset, I can accomplish this feat. But, I'd love to hear your thoughts - am I being recklessly optimistic or can I actually pull this off?

This is generally regarded as a bad idea. For reasons noted in the linked duplicate question, the process of tuning a piano is elaborate and precise - it's almost a full ritual, as the video you're watching should (hopefully!) illustrate. Musicians don't tune their own acoustic pianos, that's a job for a piano technicians. It's definitely possible to learn, but it's a career trade level of knowledge, not a DIY project.

While there is indeed a nonzero risk of damaging the instrument, it's probably fairly small if you are cautious (especially in tightening the strings).  The more compelling reason not to do this is that you're very unlikely to end up with a well tuned piano.  Learning to set a temperament takes time, and using an electronic tuner to do it is likely to lead to inferior results.  You should be prepared for the possibility of needing weeks or months of practice before you achieve a good result.

If you're prepared to throw it away after an aborted attempt, or eventually call in an experienced tuner, I wouldn't go there. Presumably it's an iron frame, if not, find a very long barge pole!

Sorry but, yes, you're being recklessly optimistic, since you admit you have zero formal training. As the duplicate question and the above remarks show, tuning a piano is a very delicate matter, and it's even more delicate for an antique instrument. At the very least, you'll end up with an inaccurate tuning (even with a modern instrument), even though you may be satisfied enough. Otherwise you may damage the instrument, breaking a string (which may be difficult to replace, including finding an adequate substitute) or even more, causing permanent damage. Note that a professional technician »

» may even tell you that they won't tune it due to the state of the instrument, or that they will only do it after lots of (costly) repairing. I don't know what video you're watching, but as many "tutorials" about aspects that normally require experienced and professional skills, you should just not do it to begin with, as long as you care about that instrument. The risk of damage is high, and the cost for a further repair could be even higher than calling a technician in the first place.

If you're careful and patient, you can probably pull it off. The fact that it's an (old) Upright Grand piano means that you're more likely to break strings than if it were a smaller spinet or a newer piano, so be careful about that. Read up on lubricating the terminations and lowering the pitch slightly before raising it to break up any corrosion at the points where the strings slide over the metal part between the singing length and the tuning pin. YouTube videos are helpful, but here's a written tutorial to get you started: https://tuneyourownpiano.com
